# Using derived methods that aren't in the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm doing a Shape class that allows you to get the positionX, positionY, and area of some shape. The derived class is a Circle, which has an added variable of radius.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape( double positionX, double positionY );
    virtual double getPositionX() = 0;
    virtual double getPositionY() = 0;
    virtual double area() = 0;

 class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle( double positionX, double positionY, double radius );
    virtual double getPositionX();
    virtual double getPositionY();
    virtual double area();
    virtual double getRadius();
```

In my main, I have an array of Shapes with the first object being a new Circle and am calling methods on this Circle.

```
int main()
{
    Shape* s[2];

    s[0] = new Circle( 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 );
    cout << s[0]->getPositionX() << endl; // Works fine.
    cout << s[0]->getPositionY() << endl; // Works fine.
    cout << s[0]->getRadius() << endl; // Doesn't work because s is a shape and my shape class has                             
                                       // no getRadius() method.
```

How do I call the getRadius() method?

Comment: If they are all circles, why not create an array of circles? If the array can contain any shapes, what should calling getRadius on a non-circle do? To answer your question, `dynamic_cast<Circle&>(*s[0]).getRadius()`

Answer (score 8):

Ug...A good design avoids this entirely. If you need to get the radius of something, then it better be something that can provide a radius. If the shape was a triangle, what should your program do?

Now the way around this is to use dynamic cast:

```
    Circle* circ = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(s[0]);
    if (circ)//check if cast succeeded
    {
       cout << circ->getRadius() << endl;
    }
```

But this code smells. In general, if you have to use dynamic_cast (which is slow and messy) then you should be rethinking your design.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: This answer is bad and shows an example of bad coding practise. Don't do it this way.**

You have to upcast it. Bad C style cast but working:

```
cout << ((Circle*)s[0])->getRadius() << endl;
```

Use C++ cast instead to be more safe. You can the base class shape a magic number. int magic_number and give each child class like Circle a different magic number, which is set in constructor.

Circle
1
Triangle 
2
Rectangle
3

etc. Then you can test if an object is a circle before you cast it to its child class.

Comment: Why recommend the bad C cast when you know C++ has a safer cast? I don't understand what the magic number suggestion is for.

Comment: I started with C and got used to this bad style. You example is way better. I will leave this answer here to let people know how to not solve this problem (magic number + c style cast). At least it is a bad example.