# Proper Design to Avoid Use of Dynamic_Cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm experiencing an issue very similar to the question asked here:
[Using derived methods that aren't in the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026885/using-derived-methods-that-arent-in-the-base-class)

In that question, the top answer, provided by IdeaHat, is to use dynamic_cast, but then he/she goes on to say that if you have to resort to that, then your design is bad. I've noticed very similar answer in other questions.

So, then, what is the proper design in such a situation?

For the sake of discussion, let's use this code:

```
enum AnimalType {
    dog = 0,
    cat
}

Class Animal {
    virtual AnimalType getType() = 0;

    void eat() {
        cout << "Ate some food!" << endl;
    }

    void sleep() {
        cout << "Zzzz..." << endl;
    }
};

Class Dog : public Animal {
    AnimalType getType() {
        return AnimalType::dog;
    }

    void fetch() {
        cout << "Fetched the stick!" << endl;
    }
};

Class Cat : public Animal {
    AnimalType getType() {
        return AnimalType::cat;
    }
};

//A factory function
Animal* shelter(AnimalType type) {
    if(type == AnimalType::dog) {
        return new Dog;
    }
    else {
        return new Cat;
    }

int main() {
    Animal* pet = shelter(AnimalType::dog);

    pet->fetch();
}
```

Essentially, I have a factory producing multiple subclasses of a particular class. Some of the subclasses contain functions not present in the parent/other subclasses, which would prevent the use of polymorphism without a workaround.

How would I implement this in a fashion that works and would also be considered "good design"?

Comment: Look deeper. Ask yourself what you've done to put yourself in a position where A) you have a generic `Animal` and B) you need to ask it to `fetch`. Either A or B is wrong, and you can only know which one by looking at your overall design, not a bunch of random test classes with animals.

Comment: You may look at [visitor Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/4579/visitor-pattern/15127/visitor-pattern-example-in-c#t=201706292151179755684) and then have a visitor for your usage which does nothing except for dog which would fetch..

Comment: @Jarod42, that looks like it might to the trick; I'll have to investigate more closely.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, I'm not sure why those are mutually exclusive. If I'm understanding what you're implying, you're saying that if I want my Dog to fetch(), I shouldn't inherit from Animal?

Comment: @AndrewKline: "*I'm not sure why those are mutually exclusive.*" Because not all `Animal`s can `fetch`; that's what it means that `Animal` doesn't have a `fetch` function. If you pass a function an `Animal` object, then it should only do things that all `Animal` objects can do. And if that function needs to make what it is passed `fetch`, then what it is passed should not be an `Animal`. So it comes down to the question of how you got yourself into such a contradictory position. And your example doesn't show that; it's too artificial.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
void functionTakingAnimal(Animal& a) {
    a.eat();
    a.sleep();
}

int main() {
    Dog pet;
    pet.fetch();
    functionTakingAnimal(pet);
}
```

Don't destroy static type information **earlier than you need to.**

Comment: I'm unclear as to how that helps me. If I get an Animal from shelter(), how will I know if it can fetch or not?

Comment: @AndrewKline If you need something that can `fetch()`, then don't get it from a source that may give you something that can't `fetch()`.